# How to retrieve specific rows that the coordinates x,y have been saved in another matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlab-guide

I have a data matrix **Data(8765x138)** that first and second columns are x and y coordinates. I have sampled some specific points in another array, **Points(2000x2)**, first and second columns in A refers to x and y, respectively. I want to extract some specific rows in Matlab that match with matrix A (both x,y). The output should be (2000x138). I tried the following code but the result is not correct.

```
newData = Data(ismember(Data(:,1),Points(:,1))& ismember(Data(:,2),Points(:,2)),:);
```

what should I do to select the rows from **Data** that its first and second columns match to my **Points** matrix. Someone please help, I feel like I've tried everything!

Comment: I don't understand your desired output. You have 2000 points, but you're outputting the entire row that matches? Can you provide a small example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I think you mix between `Points` and `A`...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ismember` with argument `rows`

```
newData = Data(ismember(Data(:,1:2),Points(:,1:2),'rows'),:);
```

But  when you are sampling it is better to save index of sampled data and use them to extract coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

It's a badly worded question, so hard to know for sure, but the solution might be to use `ismember()` to find matching rows, e.g.:

```
DataXY = Data(:,[1,2]);
tf = ismember(DataXY, Points, 'rows');
newData = Data(tf,:);
```

Comment: Which is just what [@rahnema1 suggested...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40368750/2627163)

Comment: @Justin Thank you very much for your help.